# ValueError: weights should have the same shape as a, Python with np.histogram

Tags: python

In Python, I tried to use data values from list passw to get the histogram values in each bin.
Then I tried to add weight for each count. Below I printed out the length of the data "costh" and weights list "weight":

```
passw=np.histogram(costh,bins=10,range=(-1.0,1.0))
print(len(costh),len(weight))
```

It's the same length 10000:

```
10000 10000
```

Then I add the weights:

```
passw=np.histogram(costh,bins=10,range=(-1.0,1.0),weights=weight)
```

It shows:

```
ValueError: weights should have the same shape as a.
```

How to solve this error? As I do have the same length of data and weights.

Comment: What are the _shapes_ of `costh` and `weights`? You only showed the length of their first dimensions.

Comment: (10000,) (10000, 1) this is costh and weight shape, it's weird

Comment: Try passing `weights.flatten()` to the `histogram` function to make it 1D.

Comment: @MattPitkin Flatten always makes a copy. Better to use `np.squeeze` or `.reshape(-1)` to change the view without touching the array's storage

Comment: Thanks! I simply used `np.squeeze`, and it works.